# How to insert data to a blob C#/mysql/uwp

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm trying to upload a PNG file to a mysql database blob type column.

I have searched everywhere and here is what I have so far, but I'm stuck... 
I end up with System.byte[] in the database.

```
public static byte[] ArtworkRawData

        StorageFile artworkfile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (artworkfile != null)
        {
            artworkSet = true;
            //var stream = await musicfile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            artworkFileBTN.Content = artworkfile.DisplayName;
            var stream = await artworkfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var streamBytes = await artworkfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            var bytes = new byte[(int)streamBytes.Length];
            ArtworkRawData = bytes;
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            artworkView.Source = image;
        }
```

my query looks like this:

```
if (DBC.Insert("INSERT INTO music(artwork) values('" +UploadMusicDialog.ArtworkRawData + "')")){

//do some stuff
}
```

UPDATE

```
public bool Insert(string query)
    {
        //open connection
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;

            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection();
            }

        }else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type is DBC?. You should not send the blob like that.

Comment: DBC is a class that contains my database functions

Comment: post code of Insert method

Comment: I updated the post.. refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
public bool Insert(string query, byte[] rawImage)
    {
        //open connection
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter("@rawImage", MySqlDbType.Blob);
                parameter.Value = rawImage;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;

            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection();
            }

        }else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

And call it like this:

```
if (DBC.Insert("INSERT INTO music(artwork) values(@rawImage)", UploadMusicDialog.ArtworkRawData))
{

//do some stuff
}
```

Anyway, it is not a good idea to have your query hardcoded like that. It is known for being highly unsecure.

Comment: yeah still failing

Comment: try now, what line is generating the complation error?

Comment: same thing.. I actually correct the mysqlparamter delcare before I tested... I need a minute... VS2015 just pooped out

Comment: I cant output an exception cause I'm getting an error about unreachable code to do with my messagebox....

Comment: Ahhhh.. I see I need to change the binary type to blob...I'll try that

Comment: It looks like the binary option actually inserted into the database... My computer needs a restart... I'm going to try the blob option after I restart... I'll keep you posted.